# warning on searching function of binary search tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree, binary-search

```
node* search(node* root, int data)
   {

    if(root==NULL||root->data==data)
    {
        if(root->data==data)
            cout<<"Found\n";
       
            return root;

    }
      
    if(data<root->data) 
       return search(root->left,data);

    if(data>root->data)
       return search(root->right,data);
   }
```

above code is for searching a key in a binary search tree, it is giving a warning: control reaches end of non-void function[-Wreturn-type]

**how to remove this warning ?**
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The return type of your function is `node*`.

From [IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSB23S_1.1.0.14/common/m1rhnvf.html):

> If control reaches the end of a function and no return is encountered, GCC assumes a return with no return value. However, for this, the function requires a return value. At the end of the function, add a return statement that returns a suitable return value, even if control never reaches there.

You are checking 3 conditions in your function - equal, less than and greater than.

So, compiler is curious that if none of them is satisfied, there is ought to be a return statement at the end of the function because the return type of the function is non void.

Just remove the third `if` block and directly return `search(root->right,data);` as follows:

```
node* search(node* root, int data)
{

    if(root==NULL||root->data==data)
    {
        if(root->data==data)
            cout<<"Found\n";
    
        return root;
    }
    
    if(data<root->data) 
        return search(root->left,data);

    return search(root->right,data);
}
```

This will work because, the third condition is already taken care by the above two conditions, i.e., if something is not equal or less than a value, then that is definitely greater than the value.